# Create Wordpress user when new custom post created

Tags: wordpress

I want to create custom posts from frontend and backend. And while I create posts I want to create users. At frontend I use form and wp_insert_post so it creates post as I need. At backend I use this code:

```
add_action( 'publish_user_contact', 'custom_post_user_create', 1, 3);
function custom_post_user_create($post_id){

 $user_login_id = 'user_'.random_int(100000, 999999);    

 update_post_meta($post_id, 'idr_contact_user_id', $user_login_id); 

 $password = wp_generate_password( 10, true, true );

 if (!empty($_POST['contact_email'])){
  $userdata = [
    'user_login'      => "$user_login_id",
    'user_pass'       => "$password",     
    'user_email'      => $_POST['contact_email'],    
    'display_name'    => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] .' '. $_POST['contact_last_name'] ),     
    'first_name'      => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] ),
    'last_name'       => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_last_name'] )   
  ];
} else {
  $userdata = [
    'user_login'      => "$user_login_id",
    'user_pass'       => "$password",  
    'display_name'    => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] .' '. $_POST['contact_last_name'] ),     
    'first_name'      => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] ),   
    'last_name'       => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_last_name'] )   
  ];
}
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
}
```

It creates user with custom post nut when I try to edit posts it creates more users. I tried to use new_to_publish, but it doesn't work (users don't creates). I tried to use save_post but it makes duplicates too.

How to prevent duplicates?

Comment: You have to add something unique to check if a user is already existing or not. you are giving a random id to user_login so this will not help you to check against the username is exist or not and second you are also creating a user without email when the email is not empty so in that case also you can't check against email exist.

Comment: Yes, I created meta value idr_contact_user_id before but I can't get meta value when use publish_user_contact because metas recording after post save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a check for the custom field, then the code won't be executed when editing a post.

```
add_action( 'publish_user_contact', 'custom_post_user_create', 1, 3);
function custom_post_user_create($post_id){

 $user_login_id = 'user_'.random_int(100000, 999999); 

 if(get_post_meta($post_id, "idr_contact_user_id", true) ) {
    return;
 }

 update_post_meta($post_id, 'idr_contact_user_id', $user_login_id); 

 $password = wp_generate_password( 10, true, true );

 if (!empty($_POST['contact_email'])){
  $userdata = [
    'user_login'      => "$user_login_id",
    'user_pass'       => "$password",     
    'user_email'      => $_POST['contact_email'],    
    'display_name'    => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] .' '. $_POST['contact_last_name'] ),     
    'first_name'      => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] ),
    'last_name'       => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_last_name'] )   
  ];
} else {
  $userdata = [
    'user_login'      => "$user_login_id",
    'user_pass'       => "$password",  
    'display_name'    => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] .' '. $_POST['contact_last_name'] ),     
    'first_name'      => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_first_name'] ),   
    'last_name'       => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['contact_last_name'] )   
  ];
}
$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It's works. But I don't get it. If I try to get post meta I got nothing. So how your code works? Could you please explain?

Comment: When this code is first run - the extra field is not yet filled in, so the check does not work. When this function is run during editing - the field already exists and the check does not allow to create another user. get_post_meta dont print nothing, you need  echo get_post_meta($post_id, "idr_contact_user_id", true);

Comment: I checked with var_dump but echo doesn't show meta value too. So this code doesn't check value only exists of meta field?

Comment: Make a screenshot of the code you are trying to use to print the field. This check really doesn't check the value, only the existence of the field.

Comment: I use this in the same function:
`$user_email = get_post_meta($post_id, 'idr_contact_user_email', true);
if (!empty($user_email)){ 
        $userdata = [
            'user_login'      => "$user_login_id",
            'user_pass'       => "$password",     
            'user_email'      => "$user_email",`

Comment: In this code we update only idr_contact_user_id, we dont update idr_contact_user_email field, That's why this field doesn't exist.

Comment: This field filled at post edit screen: https://yadi.sk/i/fb0lnOWcDXPfJw. Is it possible to get it in this function?

Comment: Try print_r($_POST) and see if this value is there

Comment: Yes it's here. So I get it by $_POST instead get_post_meta. Thanks a lot!